# CSS3 column-count blocks overlapping overlays

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I am implementing a multi column layout using the css3 column-count and column-gap options. Plenty of divs are arranged in 2 columns inside a main div. Problem is I want to use dropdown menus in the inner divs which overlap their borders.

The problem: The css3 columns option blocks the dropdowns from overlapping their parent div in *Google Chrome*. Tried changing z-index and overflow options.. Any ideas? Thanks!

Plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/8CqzQkvP9emIWvSXBses?p=preview

Edit: Seems like chrome is handling css3 columns quite buggy in general. I see some more problems for example as soon as I put bootstrap glyphicons into the buttons. Often two clicks are required for opening the dropdown. Also firefox is distributing the divs much more evenly among the columns. Did not find anything about those problems..?

Comment: What browser are you having a problem with??

Comment: Latest Google Chrome, screenshot visualizing the cut of part of the dropdown: http://d.pr/i/WqT - you are correct, it's working fine in Firefox.

Comment: I used Google Chrome and can't see no problem?!

Answer (score 1):

First off, `z-index` won't do anything on a nested element in comparison to its parents.  Since you're trying to overlap a column, there's no element in the DOM for it to actually overlap.  Columns aren't intended expressly for layout.  Instead, they're intended to create readable long text on horizontal layouts.

What you're seeing in Chrome is coming directly from the [W3C specification for multi-column layouts and how they should handle overflow](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-multicol/#overflow).  Setting overflow on anything here doesn't pertain to the columns, only to the column's container.

If you want to accomplish the layout you're after here, I would highly recommend you look into a grid system, like [960 Grid](http://960.gs) or [Bootstrap's grid system](http://getbootstrap.com/).